# Issue with HTML Page Resizing on web server

Tags: html, css, resize, width

I am having a difficult issue with the resizing of my web page ONLY when it's on the web server.

Locally, it works fine. It fits to the screen and looks great but when I upload it to my web server and access the page, it's zoomed it and seems to be sizing to a 1920 width.

Any advice on this?

Thanks!

```
#Web_1920___1 {
position: absolute;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: #E5E5E5;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
/*overflow: hidden;*/
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
--web-view-name: Web 1920 – 1;
--web-view-id: Web_1920___1;
--web-scale-to-fit: true;
--web-scale-to-fit-type: width;
--web-enable-deep-linking: true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try hard resetting your browser (CTRL/SHIFT + F5).
Browsers cache style by default.

On top of that, have you considered looking into writing it responsively?
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution:

Always declare your @font-face after declaring your body. Just a small mistake, but learned from it.